# Limit involving regularized gamma function and its inverse

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, special-functions, limits-and-convergence

Let

$$L(x)=Q\left(\frac{x}{2},\frac{a}{a+f(x)/\sqrt{x}}Q^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2},1-b^{1/g(x)}\right)\right)$$

where $Q(s,x)=\frac{\Gamma(s,x)}{\Gamma(s)}$ is the upper [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $\Gamma(s,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$ regularized by gamma function $\Gamma(s)$, $Q^{-1}(s,z)$ is the solution for $x$ in $z=Q(s,x)$, $a>0$ is a constant, $\frac{1}{2}<b<1$ is also a constant, and $g(x)=\omega(x)$ is a function that is asymptotically greater than $x$.

I am interested in the behavior of the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}L(x)$ for varying asymptotics of $f(x)$.  Specifically, numerical evaluations seem to indicate that when $f(x)=\omega(\sqrt{\log(x)})$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}L(x)=0$ and when $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\log(x)})$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}L(x)=1$.  However, I am having trouble proving this analytically (my usual Taylor expansion tricks don't seem to work here).  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I give a sketch of a proof.

First an approximation for the inverse incomplete gamma function, $Q^{-1}$, is needed.
Henceforth I assume that

$$
g(x)\sim \gamma x^s 
$$

for large $x$ with $s>0$. Then ($0<b<1$)

$$
1-b^{1/g(x)}\sim (\gamma x^s)^{-1}\ln\left(\frac{1}{b}\right),
$$

which is small for large $x$.

Now we use a formula due to Tricomi, which can be found [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#iv)

$$
Q(\alpha+1,\alpha+\sqrt{2 \alpha} y) = \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}(y),
$$

for $\alpha\rightarrow \infty$.

Setting $\alpha=x/2$ one gets for large $x$ (dropping constant and lower terms) the following approximation

$$
Q\left(\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2}\left(1+\frac{2 y}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\right) \sim \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}(y) .
$$

Now we choose $y$ such that the right side is approximately equal to $(\gamma x^s)^{-1}\ln\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)$. With the help of the expansion of the inverse erfc, $\text{inverfc}$ (see e.g.  [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.17#iii) .)

$$
\text{inverfc} (y) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{-\ln\left(\pi y^2 \ln \frac{1}{y}\right)} .
$$

Again using the fact that $x$ is large, we find $y\sim \sqrt{s} \sqrt{\ln x}$, keeping only the highest order in $\ln x$.

This gives

$$
Q^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2},1-b^{1/g(x)} \right) \sim \frac{x}{2}\left(1+2\sqrt{ s}\sqrt{ \frac{\ln x}{x}}\right),
$$

independent of $\gamma$ and $b$.

Insertion and once more dropping terms of lower order in $x$ (assuming $f(x)/\sqrt{x}\rightarrow 0$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$)
$$
L(x) \sim Q\left(\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2}\left[1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left(2 \sqrt{s \ln x}- \frac{f(x)}{a}\right)\right]\right).
$$

Another asymptotic formula for the incomplete gamma functions comes into play (see, e.g.,   [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#iii)):

$$
\Gamma(z,\lambda z) \sim (\lambda z)^z e^{-\lambda z}\frac{1}{z(\lambda - 1)},
$$

For this formula to be valid $\lambda > 1$.

Using the above and Stirling's formula for the $\Gamma(z)$ with $z=x/2$ and setting

$$
\lambda = \lambda(x) := 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left(2 \sqrt{s \ln x}- \frac{f(x)}{a}\right).
$$

after a lot of cancellations the result is

$$
L(x) \sim (2 \sqrt{s \ln x}- f(x)/a)^{-1}\rightarrow 0
$$

for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Note that

$$
\lambda(x)^{x/2} \sim e^{x(\lambda(x)-1)/2},
$$

which cancels exactly with the exponential term in the approximation, thus leaving only the $\sqrt{x}/(\lambda(x)-1)$.

If we have $\lambda = 1$, i.e. $f(x) = 2 a \sqrt{s \ln x}$, another formula might be used (see, e.g. [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#v))

$$
\Gamma(z,z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}  z^{z-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-z} .
$$

With this I find

$$
L(x)\sim Q \left(\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{2}\right)\sim \frac{1}{2},
$$

which is in disagreement with the numerical results. One has instead to take into account next order terms.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation!  I haven't gotten a chance to completely go through it yet, however, there are two things that I noticed right away in the beginning: 1) I am fine with the assumption of a $g(x)$ being a power function of $x$, but I think you meant $s>1$ (you have $s>0$ which I think is just a typo); 2) Are you sure that $Q(\alpha+1,\alpha+\sqrt{2\alpha}y)\approx\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(y)$?  The DLMF link you posted states that $Q(\alpha+1,\alpha+\sqrt{2\alpha}y)\approx\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(-y)$...  Does that impact the result?

Comment: Back to going through your proof and noticed that I made a mistake in my comment: indeed $Q(\alpha+1,\alpha+\sqrt{2\alpha}y)\approx \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(y)$ since Tricomi's formula in DLMF is for the complement $P(\alpha+1,\alpha+\sqrt{2\alpha}y)=1-Q(\alpha+1,\alpha+\sqrt{2\alpha}y)$...  my mistake, though point #1 in my previous comment still stands. :)  Continuing reading the proof...

Comment: I finished reading the proof -- I think it's correct (that was quite a tour de force through DLMF).  I think there is one more typo in the final approximation of $Q^{-1}$ (after "This gives"): I think you want the $\ln x$ under the square root sign (it's there for the remainder of the proof).  Regarding your last statement, my numerical evaluations weren't perfect and indeed $L(x)$ might be going to $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of 1.  Still, it looks like that there is indeed a threshold on the asymptotics of $f(x)$. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Bullmoose for going through the proof ! I had indeed to flip a lot of DLMF pages. I corrected one typo (the ln is now under the square root). Thank you for that. . $s>0$ is no typo. The proof works perfect for all $s>0$, I guess. One just needs that $g(x)$ grows infinitely as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the proof!  I really like how you inverted the $Q$ function -- that's a neat trick that I'll use in the future.  While the proof works as is, after a brief search I found [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-58-198/S0025-5718-1992-1122079-8/S0025-5718-1992-1122079-8.pdf) by Temme.  I haven't had a chance to read it in detail, but it seems to apply to a very general range of scenarios, so I am now wondering whether your derivation of $Q^{-1}$ matches the form given in that paper (I'll try to read it carefully this coming week.)